# Rspec 2 - --format html using guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rspec2, guard

In my rails project my .rspec file is as follows:

```
--color
--format progress
--format html --out tmp/spec_outputs/spec_results.html
```

When I run "rake spec" the output is as expected: I see the progress output in stdout and the html file is created in the given directory.

However, when I try to automate my tests using "bundle exec guard" the html is sent to stdout as well and the html file is not created/updated.  NOTE: I have the same issue if I just run "guard" without the "bundle exec".

My guardfile below:

```
guard 'cucumber', cli: "-p wip" do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end


guard 'rspec', :version => 2 do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara request specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rspec` command run by `guard` does not respect your `.rspec` file. You can pass `--format` argument to rspec by using `:cli` option:

```
guard 'rspec', :cli => "--color --format progress --format html --out tmp/spec_outputs/spec_results.html" do
  # ...
end
```

For more information, checkout `guard-rspec` document [guard/guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#readme).

Comment: Thanks.  You were spot-on.  I tried passing a :cli option yesterday but it didn't work.  It must not have correctly specified it.